# User will get the dialog when the user first time login to the portal. and i want to check terms & condition checkbox only first time

Tags: python, selenium, pytest, data-driven-tests

I am working on one project. and in this project, I have created an account from the master portal. and set a password for it. when users first-time log in to the portal they will get a dialog for terms & conditions. and I want to check the checkbox only one time.

This is my login method:

```
@pytest.fixture()
def PracticeLogin(setup):
    driver = setup
    driver.get(loginSheet.cell(3, 2).value)
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    login = LoginScreen(driver)
    login.SetUsername(loginSheet.cell(3, 3).value)
    login.SetPassword(loginSheet.cell(3, 4).value)
    login.SignIn()
    if "Terms & Policies" in driver.page_source:
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="modal-dialog"]//*[@class="checkbox checkbox-success"]').click()
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, Locators.continueButton).click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

I am getting `NoSuchElementException`

[This is the portal URL](https://ibis-dev.droicelabs.us/login/dispenser)

```
Email: monica.compound@mailinator.com
Pass: Test@2020
```

Comment: We can not clearly answer here since you do not share a link to that page or it's HTML

Comment: Put a print inside this `if "Terms & Policies" in driver.page_source:` and see if the code flow is going there or not

Comment: `NoSuchElementException` is very vague error as well, Please post the full error stack trace.

Comment: @Prophet I have modified my question please check it

Comment: What code line gives the `NoSuchElementException` error?

Comment: `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="modal-dialog"]//*[@class="checkbox checkbox-success"]').click()` For this line

Comment: If i will remove `in driver.page_source:` from `if "Terms & Policies" in driver.page_source:`. it will click on the checkbox and login success but when I will login second time it will return  `NoSuchElementException` for this line `"driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="modal-dialog"]//*[@class="checkbox checkbox-success"]').click()`

Comment: Try adding some sleep delay after `login.SignIn()` and let me know if it helped

Comment: @Prophet not helped. I have debugged the issue it does not go under the if statement.

Comment: @Prophet i have done in Cypress like that `cy.get('body').then($element => {
  if ($element.text().includes('Continue')) {
   cy.clickOnElementUsingXpath(patientPageSelectors.CheckBox)
   cy.clickOnElementUsingText(practiceData.continueButton)
  }
 })` it will work perfectly.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Cypress, but please let me know if my answer guess was correct?

Comment: Yes, Your and is working.  but when I log in a second time it will take some time to execute the command after login.

Comment: We can decrease the  `implicitly_wait` timeout, that's not a problem. It should be long enough to 100% catch the pop-up on it's first appearance even your internet is slow, the web site is busy etc but not too much on other hand to pass it for non-first runs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```py
@pytest.fixture()
def PracticeLogin(setup):
    driver = setup
    driver.get(loginSheet.cell(3, 2).value)
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    login = LoginScreen(driver)
    login.SetUsername(loginSheet.cell(3, 3).value)
    login.SetPassword(loginSheet.cell(3, 4).value)
    login.SignIn()
    checkboxes = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="modal-dialog"]//*[@class="checkbox checkbox-success"]')
    if checkboxes:
        checkboxes[0].click()
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, Locators.continueButton).click()
```

Comment: Thank you, it will work perfectly, but when I log in a second time it will take some time to execute the command after login. and can you please explain this?